# How to copy all column values of a dataframe into new columns of another one according to the index of the first and a column value of the second

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, data-science

I have the following dataframe 1 df1:

```
index    tech_1    tech_2   tech_3 .....
01_es      NA         NA        1
02_es       1         2         NA
03_es       2         1         2
04_es       1         NA        2
05_es       NA        NA        NA
```

and another dataframe 2 df2:

```
index        id    column_1   column_2  column_3
0         01_es       data      data       data
1         02_es       data      data       data
2         03_es       data      data       data
3         04_es       data      data       data
4         05_es       data      data       data
```

I want to "merge" df1 into df2 whenever the df1.index matches df2.id into new df2.columns keeping all the data on df2. I will perform this with several df1.

new df2:

```
index        id    column_1   column_2  column_3 tech_1    tech_2   tech_3 
0         01_es       data      data       data   NA        NA        1
1         02_es       data      data       data    1         2        NA
2         03_es       data      data       data    2         1        2
3         04_es       data      data       data    1        NA        2
4         05_es       data      data       data   NA        NA        NA
```

df1 can be quite large with a different number of columns and probably with not all the rows as df2.id. I have several files to run the script over. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

If the id column of dataframe df2 is guaranteed to be unique, you can set it as index and do the merge.

```
df2.set_index('id').merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Now for the cases where there are different columns in df1, you can define your preference by passing the "how" parameter to merge, read the documentation for details.